# What is the best way to check for the object with the most keys in a list?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list that has objects with a varying amount of keys. I want to make sure that I get the index from the list of the object with the most keys OR the reference to the object itself. What is the best way to do this?

My current approach is:

```
let index = -1;
let numKeys = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < mylistofobjects.length; i++) { 
  if(Object.keys(mylistofobjects[i]).length > numKeys) {
    index = i;
  }
}

// by the end, index has the most keys
```

Is there a smarter/shorter way to do this that would require less code in this day and age? If the way to get the object reference is shorter than the way to get the index number.. I would prefer the object reference.

Comment: Are you sure you need the *index*, rather than the actual object with the most keys? Messing with indicies manually is *usually* a bit more annoying than code needs to be. Sometimes necessary, but often not

Comment: `Object.keys(mylistofobjects.length)` are you sure that's what your code is doing ... because `.length` is a Number and won't have any keys

Comment: `Object.keys(mylistofobjects)` so, you're always checking the same object now, the list (array?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance whichever gets me to the least amount of code. Having the actual object is good if it is shorter than code that tries to get to the index.

Comment: FInally - did you want the object, the length or the index?

Comment: @Jaromanda X If getting the reference to the object itself can be done shorter than the means to get the index, I would prefer that. If the index can be retrieved more efficiently than the object, I would prefer that. Whichever is most optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `reduce`, keeping in the accumulator the object with the most keys found so far:

```
const objWithMostKeys = mylistofobjects.reduce((bestSoFar, thisObj) => (
  Object.keys(bestSoFar).length >= Object.keys(thisObj).length ? bestSoFar : thisObj
));
```

It's not entirely efficient because it checks the accumulator's number of keys on every iteration, rather than caching it, but caching it will require a bit more code:

```
let maxKeyCount = Object.keys(mylistofobjects[0]).length;
const objWithMostKeys = mylistofobjects.reduce((bestSoFar, currObj) => {
  const currKeyCount = Object.keys(currObj).length;
  if (currKeyCount > maxKeyCount) {
    maxKeyCount = currKeyCount;
    return currObj;
  }
  return bestSoFar;
});
```

This assumes that the `mylistofobjects` isn't empty. If that's a possibility, probably add a `.length` check beforehand, and return early / throw an error (or whatever you need to do) instead of proceeding.